# I need to size the imageView inside my table row programatically

Tags: android

I've tried to set my `ImageView` resized but it did not work either by bitmap or other methods I'm going to place my code so if can anyone help me how to size the `ImageView` to fit inside the table row thnx.

```
public class Test extends Activity
{
    private TableLayout Table1;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    { 
        int[] ImageArray={R.raw.hospital_image,R.raw.hotel_image};
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.favorites);
        Table1 = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.Table);
        TableRow.LayoutParams tableRowParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f);
        for(int i=0;i<ImageArray.length;i++)
        {
            TableRow TR = new TableRow(this);
            TR.setLayoutParams(tableRowParams);
            ImageView img=new ImageView(this);
            //What should i do here to resize it ???
            Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(ImageArray[i]);
            img.setImageDrawable(d); 

            TR.addView(img, new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                    TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f));

            Table1.addView(TR);
        }
    }
```

My XMl only holds these :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/Table1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 6):

try this,

```
public class ResizableImageView extends ImageView {
    public ResizableImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public ResizableImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        Drawable d = getDrawable();
        if (d == null) {
            super.setMeasuredDimension(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
            return;
        }

        int imageHeight = d.getIntrinsicHeight();
        int imageWidth = d.getIntrinsicWidth();

        int widthSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        int heightSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

        float imageRatio = 0.0F;
        if (imageHeight > 0) {
            imageRatio = imageWidth / imageHeight;
        }
        float sizeRatio = 0.0F;
        if (heightSize > 0) {
            sizeRatio = widthSize / heightSize;
        }

        int width;
        int height;
        if (imageRatio >= sizeRatio) {
            // set width to maximum allowed
            width = widthSize;
            // scale height
            height = width * imageHeight / imageWidth;
        } else {
            // set height to maximum allowed
            height = heightSize;
            // scale width
            width = height * imageWidth / imageHeight;
        }

        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
    }
}
```

use it in your layout as you would plain old `ImageView`, just change the tag, like this,

```
        <com.example.ResizableImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:padding="1px"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="..." />
```

Comment: Jeff just one question this class i ust implement to get my image resize can i paste it directly inside my current class?

Comment: this class is for am image that expands to fill the available space.

Comment: i paste it in a new class as u named it how do i call it inside my activity now in Test Activity that i've got?
I know iam asking alot but i really appreciate

Comment: I posted my XML just to let u know that it holds

Comment: replace `ImageView` with `ResizableImageView` in your code, and make sure to set all all the same attributes that you see in the XML above.

Answer (score 2):

`setLayoutParams()` should do the trick, in your case I believe you would need `TableRow.LayoutParams`, like so:

```
ImageView img = new ImageView(this);
img.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(w, h));
```

---

**Edit**

Try to set the `Drawable` before the `setLayoutParams`:

```
ImageView img = new ImageView(this);
Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(ImageArray[i]);
img.setImageDrawable(d);
img.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(w, h));
```

Comment: i sow that in another post i tried it but it kept the same resolution wen i run the app.any more solutions plz

Comment: Set the `Drawable` before the `LayoutParams` and try that

Comment: i did what u said but still nothing is happening but thank you a lot if u got any other ideas just let me know them plz

Comment: @MostafaAddam wrap imageview inside linearlayout (with params  of layout wrap content) then set to  ll layout params of tablerow