# How proportionally scale any image (of imageview) with width equal to "match_parent"?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-image, android-drawable

**I may have different drawables (large or small) and I always spans the width (match_parent) and increase or decrease the height proportionally. Maintaining the ratio.**

How is this possible?

I tried with:

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_TEST"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/test" />
```

The problem is that it increases or decreases the width and it looks bad.

[image]

Comment: Use `android:scaleType="fitStart"` and see if the result is what you are looking for.

Comment: you have to get the `width` of parentview of your `ImageView`.and accordingly you can determine the scaling factor.afterwards you can get scaled drawable and set it.

Comment: It doesn't work, the image is not stretched to fill the entire width

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Fixed. To correct this problem you need to do:

1. Custom ImageView
2. Set drawable to `"android:src"`, from code (`imageview.setImageResource()`)

Replace ImageView by ResizableImageView:

```
<"the name of your package".ResizableImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_test"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
```

**ResizableImageView.class**

```
    public class ResizableImageView extends ImageView {
        public ResizableImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
        }

        public ResizableImageView(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
            Drawable d = getDrawable();
            if (d == null) {
                super.setMeasuredDimension(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
                return;
            }

            int imageHeight = d.getIntrinsicHeight();
            int imageWidth = d.getIntrinsicWidth();

            int widthSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
            int heightSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

            float imageRatio = 0.0F;
            if (imageHeight > 0) {
                imageRatio = imageWidth / imageHeight;
            }
            float sizeRatio = 0.0F;
            if (heightSize > 0) {
                sizeRatio = widthSize / heightSize;
            }

            int width;
            int height;
            if (imageRatio >= sizeRatio) {
                // set width to maximum allowed
                width = widthSize;
                // scale height
                height = width * imageHeight / imageWidth;
            } else {
                // set height to maximum allowed
                height = heightSize;
                // scale width
                width = height * imageWidth / imageHeight;
            }

            setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
        }
    }
```

Solution: [I need to size the imageView inside my table row programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12982404/i-need-to-size-the-imageview-inside-my-table-row-programatically)