# Universal image loader image scale

Tags: android, imageview, universal-image-loader, image-scaling

I am using Universal Image Loader in my app.

It is the best libary to download images, but I have one problem.

I download images that they are smaller than width of device.

I need the image have width = device width and scaled height.

Any idea how I can do this?

Comment: Just check for the property  android:scaleType="fitXY"

Comment: You can use `android:scaleType="fitXY"` or `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` for your `ImageView`.

Comment: Have you got what you want to achieve @Unmerciful ????

Comment: fitXY wrong scaling when image resolution is smalerr than device width.

center cropp croping my image..

I found solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12982404/i-need-to-size-the-imageview-inside-my-table-row-programatically

Answer (score 1):

you can use imageview like this

```
<ImageView
 android:id="@+id/imageView_clock"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:scaleType="centerCrop"
 android:src="@drawable/ic_icon" />
```

and its depends on your image size from web

```
 android:scaleType="centerCrop" // use this
```